# VBA IF statement Loop If values are equal

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

```
Sub DataEntry()

Dim col, ro, col2 As Double
Dim sCellVal As String
col = 0
col2 = 0
ro = 0

Dim cel As Range


sCellVal = Range("D9").Value


If sCellVal Like "Night" Then


For Each cel In Worksheets("Service").Range("C40:NR40")


If cel.Value = Range("B9").Value Then
col = cel.Column

ElseIf cel.Value = Range("C9").Value Then
col2 = cel.Column
Exit For
End If

Next cel


If col = 0 Then
MsgBox "Date Not Found"
Exit Sub
End If


For Each cel In Worksheets("Service").Range("A40:A80")


If cel.Value = Range("F17").Value Then
ro = cel.Row
Exit For
End If


Next cel


If ro = 0 Then
MsgBox "Name Not Found"
Exit Sub
End If


With Worksheets("Service")
.Range(.Cells(ro, col), .Cells(ro, col2)).Value = Range("W2").Value
End With


MsgBox "Record added (Night Pay)"


Exit Sub
End If


For Each cel In Worksheets("Service").Range("C1:NR1")

If cel.Value = Range("B9").Value Then
col = cel.Column

ElseIf cel.Value = Range("C9").Value Then
col2 = cel.Column

Exit For
End If

Next cel


If col = 0 Then
MsgBox "Date Not Found"
Exit Sub
End If


For Each cel In Worksheets("Service").Range("A1:A40")


If cel.Value = Range("F17").Value Then
ro = cel.Row
Exit For
End If


Next cel


If ro = 0 Then
MsgBox "Name Not Found"
Exit Sub
End If

With Worksheets("Service")
.Range(.Cells(ro, col), .Cells(ro, col2)).Value = Range("W2").Value
End With


MsgBox "Record added!"


End Sub
```

This code searches for a date range in cell (Column)B9 & C9 & (Row)F17 and puts the value from W2 in the range where all these meet. The issue occurs when B9&C9 contain the same date, the if statement loops until i get a 400 error.

I'm looking for a way that when B9&C9 equal each other, it still runs the code and puts the value from "W2" into where the only B9&F17 intersect with each other. The only way i know how to do this, is check if the ranges equal each other at the start of the code, then copy a similar version of what i have without:

```
    ElseIf cel.Value = Range("C9").Value Then
col2 = cel.Column
Exit For
End If
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this, without copying the full code again and using GoTo.

Sorry guys, im quite new to VBA... Any help will me greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you should remove the ElseIf and use two or possibly three independent If statements.

```
col = 0: col2 = 0

For Each cel In Worksheets("Service").Range("C40:NR40")

    If cel.Value = Range("B9").Value Then col = cel.Column

    If cel.Value = Range("C9").Value Then col2 = cel.Column

    if col<>0 and col2<>0 then exit for

Next cel
```